# Transforming 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know the theorem stating any 2nd order ODE of the form:
$$
p(x)X''(x) + q(x)Y'(x) + r(x)X(x) = 0
$$
can be transformed into 
$$
P(x)X'' +Q(x)X' + RX = 0
$$
By multiplying the original ODE by $$e^{\int \frac{q-p'}{p}dx}.$$

Anyway so the stated ODE is:
$$
(A^2 - x^2)Y''(x) - xY'(x) + (n^2)Y(x) = 0,\qquad  -A < x < A
$$
let $x = A\cos(z)$, $0 < z < \pi$.
And I'm meant to transform it into:
$$
Y'' + (n^2)Y = 0,\qquad 0 < z < \pi
$$
No luck in doing it though.... Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $U(z)=Y(A\cos z)$. Then 
$$
U'(z)=Y'(A\cos z)·(-A\sin z)
$$
 and 
$$
U''(z)=Y''(A\cos z)·A^2\sin^2 z-Y'(A\cos z)·A\cos z.
$$ 
Now with $A^2\sin^2=A^2-x^2$ you can proceed to verify the transformation of the differential equation.

---

Using $x=x(z)=A \cos z$ one gets from the original differential equation
$$
U''(z)=(A^2-x^2)Y''(x)-x·Y'(x)=-n^2Y(x)=-n^2U(z)
$$
and thus $U$ satisfies the differential equation $U''+n^2U=0$.

It is generally a bad idea to use the same symbol for two different objects in the same calculation.

---

As for the first consideration, it is unclear from your formulation what the normal form is expected to be. Let $A'=a$ and $Y=e^A·X$, then 
$$
Y'=e^A·X'+ae^A·X
$$
 and 
$$
Y''=e^A·X''+2·ae^A·X'+a^2e^A·X
$$ 
so that
\begin{align}
pY''&=e^A·(-qX'-rX)+2·p·ae^A·X'+p·a^2e^A·X\\&=(2pa-q)·(Y'-aY)+(pa^2-r)·Y
\end{align}

From this it seems likely that you want to achieve the self-adjoint normal form for Sturm-Liouville equations or something similar. In this case, the wanted form is
$$
0=(pY')'+RY=pY''+p'Y'+RY
$$
so that $q-2pa=p'$ or $a=\frac{q-p'}{2p}$ and thus $R=r+pa^2-aq=r+\frac{p'^2-qp'}{4p}$

Comment: LutzL I'm not sure how to proceed.... Using p,q,p' i get (cos(x)-Acos(x)sin(x))/(Asin(x))^2)..... most likely not meant to integrate that. Please give more detail on the method.